# Extract metadata without uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, metadata

I hava a Ruby on Rails application that works with video playlists. Now I would like to extract timecode information from the video file without uploading it to the server (takes to long). Is the possible?
If it is not possible, is there a way to export te metadata locally and uploads these xmls (for example) to the server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: locally you mean from the browser ?

Comment: Yes, I mean from the browser

Answer (score 0):

afaik, this is not possible in browsers that do not support `File API`. Take a look at [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) and the way it allows user to identify the file extension before upload.